# How can I access a parent element using selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I access the parent of an element using Selenium?

For instance, I already have an inner element defined by `class="angle"`. How to get an outer `a` element?

```
<a href="/path/topik/12/"><i class="angle"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try using `xpath` locator as below :-

- using [parent axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/parent) :

  ```
  .//*[@class='angle']/parent::a
  ```

  Or

  ```
  .//*[@class='angle']/..
  ```
- using [child axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/child) :

  ```
  .//a[child::*[@class='angle']]
  ```